# How to get live tweets in c# using tweetinvi library

Tags: c#, tweetinvi

Im using tweetinvi in c#  to get stream of tweets for analysis , is there a way i can get real-Time or live filtered tweets

Comment: What have you tried, and what didn't work?  If you found the library, I'm sure you've looked at the [wiki?](https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Streams)

Answer (score 1):

I am the developer of Tweetinvi. I am not sure if yoiur read the [Filtered Stream documentation](https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Filtered-Streams).

But here is how you can do what you want in few lines:

```
var stream = Stream.CreateFilteredStream();

// Add all your filters with AddTrack
stream.AddTrack("tweetinvi");
stream.AddTrack("rest");

stream.MatchingTweetReceived += (sender, args) =>
{
    // This event will be invoked every time a tweet created is matching your criteria
    var tweet = args.Tweet;


    // If you want to get all the matching values
    var matchingTracks = args.MatchingTracks;
    var matchingFollowers = args.MatchingFollowers;
    var matchingLocations = args.MatchingLocations;

    // If you want to know which criteria has matched
    var matchedOn = args.MatchOn;
};

stream.StartStreamMatchingAllConditions();
```